# How can I build a forked node module using NPM?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I have forked the react-sortable-tree module in github, made a modification and installed it into my project. I need to now build the package but I am getting the following error log when i do `npm run-script build` in the root folder of the package where its package.json is located. Line 11 seems to be where things go wrong but I have no idea what the error is saying. How do I build this module?

Here is the module on git... https://github.com/lewishornsby/react-sortable-tree

```
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.4.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run-script',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v14.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle react-sortable-tree@2.8.0~prebuild: react-sortable-tree@2.8.0
6 verbose lifecycle react-sortable-tree@2.8.0~prebuild: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle react-sortable-tree@2.8.0~prebuild: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/badmin/Documents/nodeHome/lewishornsby/react-amplify/node_modules/react-sortable-tree/node_modules/.bin:/Users/badmin/Documents/nodeHome/lewishornsby/react-amplify/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
8 verbose lifecycle react-sortable-tree@2.8.0~prebuild: CWD: /Users/badmin/Documents/nodeHome/lewishornsby/react-amplify/node_modules/react-sortable-tree
9 silly lifecycle react-sortable-tree@2.8.0~prebuild: Args: [ '-c', 'yarn run lint && yarn run clean' ]
10 info lifecycle react-sortable-tree@2.8.0~prebuild: Failed to exec prebuild script
11 verbose stack Error: react-sortable-tree@2.8.0 prebuild: `yarn run lint && yarn run clean`
11 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
11 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
11 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
11 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
11 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
12 verbose pkgid react-sortable-tree@2.8.0
13 verbose cwd /Users/badmin/Documents/nodeHome/lewishornsby/react-amplify/node_modules/react-sortable-tree
14 verbose Darwin 19.5.0
15 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.4.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run-script" "build"
16 verbose node v14.4.0
17 verbose npm  v6.14.6
18 error code ELIFECYCLE
19 error syscall spawn
20 error file sh
21 error errno ENOENT
22 error react-sortable-tree@2.8.0 prebuild: `yarn run lint && yarn run clean`
22 error spawn ENOENT
23 error Failed at the react-sortable-tree@2.8.0 prebuild script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Do you have `yarn` installed on your computer? you can find out with `yarn -v` at the command line. If it's installed you'll see a version number.

Comment: I did not! but now I do and after retrying I get the same log as I posted above but with `yarn run v1.22.10
warning ../../../../../../package.json: No license field
$ eslint src

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 6.8.0.

No files matching the pattern "src" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
`

Comment: Doing `../../../../../../` from the modules directory takes me right back to root on my machine. I am so confused by this

Comment: did you run `npm install` before trying to build?

Comment: Yeah, was that where I went wrong?